# Spring CrudRepository findByInventoryIds(List<Long> inventoryIdList) - equivalent to IN clause

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In Spring CrudRepository, do we have support for "IN clause" for a field? ie something similar to the following?

```
 findByInventoryIds(List<Long> inventoryIdList)
```

If such support is not available, what elegant options can be considered? Firing queries for each id may not be optimal.

Answer (score 435, accepted):

`findByInventoryIdIn(List<Long> inventoryIdList)` should do the trick.

The HTTP request parameter format would be like so:

```
Yes ?id=1,2,3
No  ?id=1&id=2&id=3
```

The complete list of JPA repository keywords can be found in the [current documentation listing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords). It shows that `IsIn` is equivalent – if you prefer the verb for readability – and that JPA also supports `NotIn` and `IsNotIn`.

If `inventoryId` has the primary key, you can simply use `yourRepo.findAll(inventoryIdList)`.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly I was looking for. Do they have it documented in CrudRepository page, or discover by reading the code?

Comment: Thanks. That "gem is hidden in the appendix B", rightly so :)

Comment: For the method signature:
List<Person> findByIdIn(List<Integer> ids);

I get the error:
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "(1, 2)"

Comment: When accessing this search method via Spring Data REST How would you specify multiple inventoryIds in an HTTP GET request?

Comment: @OliverGierke following repository method `@Modifying
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM badge WHERE threshold_type=?1 AND threshold<?2 AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM badge_achieved WHERE user_id=?3)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Badge> getAchievableBadgeByThreshold(BadgeThresholdType thresholdType, Integer threshold, Long userId);` is not returning any result. If I run same query with same bounded parameter it's working. Any hint?

Comment: I'm curious does author of the question(or even answer) checked the number of queries that spawns by accepted solution.
From the question: "Firing queries for each id may not be optimal.".
Accepted code will do query per entity. So if inventoryIdList.size == 100 this code will do 100 selects with possible joins and stuff.

Comment: If `inventoryId` has the primary key, you can simply use `yourRepo.findAll(inventoryIds)`

Answer (score 139):

For any method in a Spring CrudRepository you should be able to specify the @Query yourself.  Something like this should work:

```
@Query( "select o from MyObject o where inventoryId in :ids" )
List<MyObject> findByInventoryIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> inventoryIdList);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Was looking for a "more cleaner" solution i.e without writing the @Query.

Comment: Oliver Gierke is the man that would know the answer to this and he has the "more cleaner" solution. You should accept his answer.

Comment: Great! I used a `Set<String>` as a parameter, worked well.

Comment: what if I want to pass 2 paramemeters to my method one list and other a normal string  , will that work? if yes how shall I name my method

Answer (score 45):

Yes, that is supported.

Check the documentation provided [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for the supported keywords inside method names.

You can just define the method in the repository interface without using the **@Query** annotation and writing your custom query. In your case it would be as followed:

```
List<Inventory> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids);
```

I assume that you have the **Inventory** entity and the **InventoryRepository** interface. The code in your case should look like this:

**The Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Inventory implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private Long id;

  // other fields
  // getters/setters

}
```

**The Repository**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface InventoryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Inventory, Long> {

  List<Inventory> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids);

}
```

Comment: This works for all interfaces that are extending the **CrudRepository** interface.

Comment: This won't work if the ids size is over 1000 or certain size depending on the DB. How about this?    **List<Inventory> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable);**