# How to use IN operator in where clause of SpringBoot Cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I am trying to run following query from SpringBoot repository

```
@Query("select * from c where id1 =?0 and id2 =?1 and id3 =?2 and c1 =?3 and year in :year and month in :month and day in :day and hour in :hour and minute in :minute"
public List<Counter> findCWithinRangeIn(
    @Param("id1") String id1,
    @Param("id2") String id2,
    @Param("id3") String id3,
    @Param("c1") String c1,
    @Param("year") List<Integer> year,
    @Param("month") List<Integer> month,
    @Param("day") List<Integer> day, 
    @Param("hour") List<Integer> hour,
    @Param("minute") List<Integer> minute);
```

But always hitting error : Invalid amount of bind variables.

Please suggest on how to proceed further.

Note: I did follow [Spring CrudRepository findByInventoryIds(List<Long> inventoryIdList) - equivalent to IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987292/spring-crudrepository-findbyinventoryidslistlong-inventoryidlist-equivalen) but it did not work for me.

I want to execute something like:

```
select * from c
where id1 ="xyz" and 
      id2 ="abc" and 
      id3 ="pqr" and 
      c1 = "Sample" and
      year IN (2016,2017) and
      month IN (9,10,11) and
      day IN (19,20,24) and
      hour IN (23, 13) and
      minute IN (50, 51, 53)
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, it bothers me that you're mixing binding methods.  You're using ?0, ?1, etc, but you are naming your parameters (id1, id2).  What happens if you change the ?0 to :id1 and the ?1 to :id2 etc?

Comment: That also doesnot work

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to specify custom query this could work for you (based on method name)

```
public List<Counter> findAllById1AndId2AndId3AndC1AndYearInAndMonthInAndDayInAndHourInAndMinuteIn(String id1, STring id2, String id3, String c1, List<Long> years, List<Long> months, List<Long> days, List<Long> hours, List<Long> minutes)
```

note: in your Counter entity the field's names must match the names of attribute names specified in method name.

Comment: I tried this but its not working and I am getting "invalid number of bind variables" error.