# How can I use all(array[]) in a native query with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I've tried to do a native query with Spring Boot using `all(array[])` function, however, I couldn't make it correctly. I don't know the quantity of Strings that I'll pass, it's a dynamic quantity. Can you guys help me on this, please?

I've tried using `List<String>`, `String[]` and just `String` as below:

1. passing `String` and in the query `all(array[:texto])`: no errors, however, no results.
2. passing `List<String>` and in the query `all(array[:texto])`:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying ~~* record
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

3. passing `String[]` and in the query `all(array[:texto])`:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying ~~* bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

4. passing `String[]` and in the query `all(array[CAST(:texto AS TEXT)])`: no errors, however, no results.

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE nome ILIKE all(array[:texto])", nativeQuery=true)
public List<Tag> findPacotesByTexto(@Param("texto") List<String> texto);
```

**EDITED:**

```
@Entity
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="pacote_id")
    private Pacote pacote;

    Tag() {

    }

    public Tag (String nome, Pacote pacote) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.pacote = pacote;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public Pacote getPacote() {
        return pacote;
    }

}
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share the `Tag` also, just in case.

Comment: I've added now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same trouble casting the list to a text[] using spring + hibernate & native query

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55179555/335264 for a working solution
(uses two postgresql functions to do the casting)

Answer (score -1):

In a native query approach, the SQL is passed exactly to be executed as is what it's written. And I think the framework could not serialize your collection as the required pattern `all(array[?, ?, ?, ...])`. In that case, you should convert your parameter before passing to the method or change the approach to not using the native query.

Comment: What do you mean with "converter your parameter before passing to the method"?

Comment: I mean rather passing a collection, you should pass only a string follows the pattern [?, ?, ...].

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't return the result to me.. And If I execute the same query through the database, I get a lot of results

Comment: Did you try with only one single element to filter?

Comment: Yes, I did. With one element I can get the results, but with more the one I always got errors

Comment: I think that's the conversion problem. What the SQL query needs is ['xxx', 'yyy'], and the first and last of single quote ```'``` are provided by the framework already, you need to handle the middle ones

Comment: Should I pass a String or a List<String> to the query?

Comment: If you want to stick with this approach, you should pass a String but that should be converted in this format ```xxx', 'yyy```. But it's a bit misleading. I would recommend you to change your approach not using the native query