# How do you create a custom Spring JPA query using "IN"?

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a parameter of integers. I need to write a custom Spring JPA query where the equivalent SQL would be . . . `AND x.propertyStatusId IN (1,2)` . . .

I see in the Spring Data JPA documentation the keyword is "IN" as in `"findByAgeIn(Collection<Age> ages)"` that translates to "where x.age in ?1" But I get an error. I am using an arrayList of integers.

```
ArrayList<Integer> propertyStatusId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
propertyStatusId.add(1);
propertyStatusId.add(2);
findByPropertyOwnerIdAndIn(propertyStatusId)AndListingDateGreaterThanEqual(user.getId(),propertyStatusId, ListingDate, pageable);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring CrudRepository findByInventoryIds(List<Long> inventoryIdList) - equivalent to IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987292/spring-crudrepository-findbyinventoryidslistlong-inventoryidlist-equivalen)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an entity called `Product` defined as below:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Date createDate;

// getters & setters 

}
```

If you would need to query based on `title`, `List of ids` and `greater than or equal to createDate` then you can define the method like below:

```
List<Product> findByTitleAndIdInAndCreateDateGreaterThanEqual(String title, List<Integer> ids, Date createDate);
```

Comment: yes this compiled and helped me get past the compilation errors around the construction of this specific part. I am still having an issue with the error about it doesn't recognize the property name for some reason. But I will resolve that as I have had that before ( I am aware it is the entity name not the SQL name etc). Thanks

Comment: I'm glad to hear this. Thank you @STP!