# Spring Data Method Name for "IN" (Multiple Values)

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to automatically create a Spring Data method based on name which would do

```
delete from USER_ROLES_T where identifier = :identifier and roleId in (:roleIds)
```

If I didn't have the IN, it would be straightforward -- this is working:

`void deleteByIdentifierAndRoleId(String identifier, long roleId);`

But how to wire the IN into the name without going through annotations?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords: `deleteByIdentifierAndRoleIdIn`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring CrudRepository findByInventoryIds(List<Long> inventoryIdList) - equivalent to IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987292/spring-crudrepository-findbyinventoryidslistlong-inventoryidlist-equivalen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one
   `void deleteByIdentifierAndRoleIdIn(String identifier, long roleId);`

It would helpful to you.