# How can I write a repository method for this situation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know this isn't the best way to define a car class, but I got curious and I ended up writing this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String model;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
        name="ACCESSORY",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
    )
    @Column(name="ACCESSORIES")
    private List<String> accessories;

    //getters and setters
}
```

and its repository

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {   
}
```

Now, considering that I want to create a repository method that finds all the cars that meet a given list of accessories, how can I do it? I was thinking about a method like `findById()` or something.
By the way, feel free if you want to answer in a way that "Accessories" is an entity.

Disclaimer: Yes, I tried the method `List<Car> findByAccessoriesIn(List<String> as);` but it brings any car that has at least one of the elements inside the list. I want all the cars that have all items inside the list.

Comment: Are you tring findAllByAccessories(List<String> as)

Answer (score 0):

“finds all the cars that meet a given list of accessories“

If i understood correctly then -
findByAccessoriesIn(List yourStrList) should work in this case.

A similar thread is here:
[Spring CrudRepository findByInventoryIds(List<Long> inventoryIdList) - equivalent to IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987292/spring-crudrepository-findbyinventoryidslistlong-inventoryidlist-equivalen)

For List in jpa we use “in” where “i” is in caps.

Comment: Kind of. 'IN' clause brings any car that have at least one accessory. I want to bring only the cars that have all of the accessories inside the list.

Comment: Yeah pass those accessories string you want to find cars for. And I guess thats what you are looking for. Try it.

Comment: It brings any car