# Is there an efficient way to find certain records from repository using a list of ids?

Tags: java, crud

I want to fetch certain records from my CRUD repository using a list of ids and currently my code looks like this:

```
  public List<Document> getDocuments(List<String> idList) {
        List<Document> allDocumentList = repository.findAll();
        List<Document> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String id : idList) {
            resultList.add(allDocumentList.stream()
                    .filter(document -> document.getId().equals(id))
                    .findFirst().get());
        }
        return resultList;
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this? Basically I'm thinking about a situation where the repository has a very large number of records.

Comment: This may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987292/spring-crudrepository-findbyinventoryidslistlong-inventoryidlist-equivalen

Comment: Yes, it was exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

you can filter records on DB side

```
SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id IN ($idList)
```